# Undefined or defined index ? Decide 

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-server, undefined-index

I have strange problem.

```
Line 61: $this->_currentRoute = Default_Model_Routes::getInstance()->getCurrentRoute();
.......... other code ..........
Line 86: var_dump(isset($this->_currentRoute['url']));
Line 87: var_dump($this->_currentRoute['url']);
Line 88: if ($this->_currentRoute['url'] == $currentUrl)
Line 89:     $navigation[$key]['active'] = true;
Line 90: var_dump($this->_currentRoute);
```

This is result:

```
bool(true)
string(62) "cs/Polozka-menu-1/Polozka-menu-1-1/Polozka-menu-1-1-1/Clanek-1"
array(17) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(62) "cs/Polozka-menu-1/Polozka-menu-1-1/Polozka-menu-1-1-1/Clanek-1"
  ["type"]=>
  string(7) "article"
  ............
}
```

And in the error log:

```
[09-Mar-2011 19:49:32] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in ...file... on line 87
[09-Mar-2011 19:49:32] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in ...file... on line 88
```

Please, if you have any ideas where could be problem or how to fix, tell me.
Thank you :)

I have tried another test:

```
$test = array();
echo $test['lol'];
```

With this result:

```
Notice: Undefined index: lol in ...file... on line 92
```

Somethink really interesting: THIS 'lol' error is displayed in output, BUT the 'url' error IS NOT ! It is only in the log ... why ????? It's same file, line under the 'url' var_dump() ... crazy

Comment: What's `var_dump($this->_currentRoute)` give you?  Chances are that there's no `url` key in that array.

Comment: ... it gives array with route info, including 'url' ...

Comment: Can you provide the output of that var_dump in your post?

Comment: Wow, that's pretty freaky.  `url` is quite obviously there.  I've got nothin'...

Comment: I hope'd you tell me something else :D ... I just saw it in the log so "Ahh I forgotten to check post or something, lets fix it..." ... "...wtf" :D It's really bugging me

Comment: What's the value of `array_key_exists('url', $this->_currentRoute);`?  It'd better darn well be `true`...

Comment: ... check the answer bellow, it dump's true

Comment: Ahahaha, yeah, that makes no sense.

Comment: ... I'll wait some time for next answers and then I'll go report a php logger bug :D

Comment: ...take a look at my post - I've added another interesting example

Comment: Yeah, something is very not right here.  Disable all your custom error handling code?

Comment: ... I don't use custom error handling ... I tried php-cli and the error doesn't shows in log ... Sooo most probably it's the Zend's fail ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happens if you assign `$this->_currentRoute` to a variable first?

```
$route = $this->_currentRoute;
var_dump(array_key_exists('url', $route));
var_dump(isset($route['url']));
print "PRINTING: ".$route['url'];
die("ENDING ON LINE [".__LINE__."] !!!");
```

#### Solved (see comments)

This was unfortunately an issue with Zend Server, or bleeding edge PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: bool(true), 
bool(true),
cs/Polozka-menu-1/Polozka-menu-1-1/Polozka-menu-1-1-1/Clanek-1 AND exact error saying that index is undefined

Comment: You are saying it prints out cs/Polozka-men... (which is the url)???  I think your problem may be related to something else, I edited my post - change your code to follow and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, it print's everything correctly. I don't think that problem is related to code - it is perfect and simple ... but, where is the problem then ? ...

Comment: Here is result: bool(true), bool(true), PRINTING: cs/Polozka-menu-1/Polozka-menu-1-1/Polozka-menu-1-1-1/Clanek-1, ENDING ON LINE [90] !!!

Comment: No error then? - this means the index error is happening somewhere else, or you have a PHP module/shared object or distribution of PHP that is unstable.

Comment: nope ... [09-Mar-2011 20:39:15] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in ...file... on line 89

Comment: @GRoNGoR Does it say "...file..." or is it in the exact same file. How are you running it? mod_php, cgi, command line? what version of php? What happens if you enable inline error reporting - to show errors for everything?

Comment: ...wow, now I found really fascinating ... if I do $test = array(); echo $test['lol']; ... it will throw undefined index too - BUT in code :) so I have display_errors enable ... I am running it locale - Zend Community Server, PHP version 5.3.3

Comment: To be honest with you, we ran Zend Server with PHP 5.3.x - I would say stay away, its a buggy pile.  Stick with the mainstream open-source and if you want opcode caching use APC.  Try running from the command-line see if it does the same thing (its a separate executable)

Comment: ... I don't use it in production - there I use simple Apache && PHP instalation :) ... this is just for "homecooking" - suited with Zend Studio ... I will try cli and post a result

Comment: I tried php-cli and the error doesn't shows in log ... Sooo most probably it's the Zend's fail ...

Comment: Open Source wins again! (hehehe) glad you figured out the issue, now hopefully you don't ever get a WSOD (white screen of death).  PS if you are a developer doing your own work, try out Python some time - I made the switch for web development two years ago, couldn't be happier.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I think that PHP is simply "more supported" ... but I want to learn Java soon :) Thank you for help - I thought that it will be bug in something most probably :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not you errors?
Try to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

And also see method `Default_Model_Routes::getInstance()->getCurrentRoute()::__get()`

[Read this](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#82220)

Comment: yes, the really are ... I don't really understand what do you mean by that method ... getCurrentRoute() return simple array - and the index is defined as you can see in my var_dump() ... by the way, if I do var_dump() on 'caption' or 'content' index, it retrieves it correctly too, but alse throws same error ...

Comment: Try this $this->_currentRoute['url'] = 'test'; var_dump($this->_currentRoute['url']);

Comment: ... this doesn't throw error ... but it doesn't help me neither :D ... it's not problem in 'url' index by the way, problem is within ALL indexies in this array ... they shows, works and exist - but throws error ... *lol*